# Order LINQ query elements by a collection of numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, compare, compareto

This is a partially defined function that I'm using to retrieve the specified lines of a textfile, by passing the index of the lines I want:

```
Public Shared Function GetLines(ByVal sourceFilepath As String,
                                ByVal lineNumbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As IEnumerable(Of String)

    Return File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilepath, encoding).
                Select(Function(line As String, index As Integer)
                            Return New With
                                   {
                                       Key .line = line,
                                       Key .index = index + 1
                                   }
                        End Function).
                Where(Function(con) lineNumbers.Contains(con.index)).
                OrderBy(Function(x) x.index.CompareTo(lineNumbers(x.index))).
                Select(Function(con) con.line)

End Function
```

Example usage:

```
GetLines("C:\file.txt", {1, 5, 6, 2} ' Linenumbers 1, 5, 6, and 2.
```

The problem is that I need to preserve the order of the lines, in the same order which I specified the indexes, so the function should order the query elements by that order {1, 5, 6, 2} but instead of that I get the lines in this order: {1, 2, 5, 6}.

How can I fix the evaluation that I'm doing at the `OrderBy` extension to return the expected results?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
OrderBy(Function(x) x.index.CompareTo(lineNumbers(x.index)))
```

To:

```
OrderBy(Function(x) lineNumbers.ToList().IndexOf(x.index))
```

Alternatively, if you changed the type of the `lineNumbers` parameter from `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` to `List(Of Integer)`, then you wouldn't need to call the `ToList` method.

Although, I have to say, while I love LINQ because it makes the code so much more readable, this is pushing the limits and is arguably less readable than writing the looping algorithm manually.  But, to each their own :)

Comment: thanks but I think you answered before I'd modified the code to avoid that "unreadableness" issue, I've stripped out some unnecessary parts of the query to avoid messing with anonym types, if you see, the code above does not have an index property to access, I still can do it in that way? ...and how?. or I should keep using the other query? .

Comment: No.  I think you need to go back to the way you had it before where you were including the index tied to each line item so that you can then order them by the index.  If you don't include that in the results of the `Select`, then there is no way to know, in subsequent methods, what the original indices were.